# How can I force a throttled observable to update immediately?

Tags: knockout.js, computed-observable

I show or hide a "Loading" indicator on my UI by binding its visibility to an observable named `waiting`, which is defined like this:

```
// Viewmodel
var outstandingRequests = ko.observable(0);

// true if any requests are outstanding
var waiting = ko.computed(function() {
    return outstandingRequests() > 0;
}.extend({ throttle: 500 });

// These are called when AJAX requests begin or end
function ajaxBegin() {
    outstandingRequests(++outstandingRequests());
}
function ajaxEnd() {
    outstandingRequests(--outstandingRequests());
}

<!-- View -->
<div data-bind="visible: waiting">Please wait, loading...</div>
```

I'm throttling the `waiting` observable because I don't want the loading message to appear unless the request is taking a long time (>500ms in this case), to increase the perceived speed of the application. The problem is that once a long-running request finishes, the loading indicator doesn't *disappear* until an additional 500ms has passed. Instead, when the last outstanding request finishes, I want `waiting` to flip to false *immediately*.

My first attempt at a fix involved using `valueHasMutated()`, but the update is still delayed.

```
function ajaxEnd() {
    outstandingRequests(--outstandingRequests());
    // If that was the last request, we want the loading widget to disappear NOW.
    outstandingRequests.valueHasMutated(); // Nope, 'waiting' still 500ms to update :(
}
```

How can I bypass the throttle extension and force `waiting` to update immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want is to delay the notifications from the `waiting` observable when it becomes `true`. This can be done by intercepting the `notifySubscribers` function of the observable:

```
var originalNotifySubscribers = this.isWaiting.notifySubscribers,
    timeoutInstance;
this.isWaiting.notifySubscribers = function(value, event) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutInstance);
    if ((event === 'change' || event === undefined) && value) {
        timeoutInstance = setTimeout(function() {
            originalNotifySubscribers.call(this, value, event);
        }.bind(this), 500);
    } else {
        originalNotifySubscribers.call(this, value, event);
    }
};
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/Pk6mH/

EDIT:
I just thought of another, possibly better, solution for your particular case. Since the `waiting` observable only depends on one other observable, you can create a manual subscription that updates the `waiting` observable:

```
var timeoutInstance;
this.isLoading.subscribe(function(value) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutInstance);
    if (value) {
        timeoutInstance = setTimeout(function() {
            this.isWaiting(true);
        }.bind(this), 500);
    } else {
        this.isWaiting(false);
    }
}, this);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/wCJHT/

Answer (score 4):

When you extend an observable, the extender typically wraps the observable with another with the desired behavior.  You could keep a reference to the original observable which will allow you to make direct writes to it all while exposing your throttled version of the observable normally.

e.g.,

```
var myObservable = ko.observable('foo');
var myThrottledObservable = myObservable.extend({ throttle: 500 });
myThrottledObservable('bar'); // delayed
myObservable('baz'); // immediate
```

In your particular use case, rather than throttling the `waiting` observable, throttle the `outstandingRequests` observable and use the throttled value in `waiting`.

```
var outstandingRequests = ko.observable(0);

// throttled requests for the waiting observable
var throttledOutstandingRequests = outstandingRequests.extend({ throttle: 500 });

// true if any requests are outstanding
var waiting = ko.computed(function() {
    return throttledOutstandingRequests() > 0;
};

// These are called when AJAX requests begin or end
function ajaxBegin() {
    outstandingRequests(++outstandingRequests());
}
function ajaxEnd() {
    outstandingRequests(--outstandingRequests());
}
```

Writes to your `outstandingRequests` observable happen immediately but your `waiting` observable will effectively be throttled.

---

Alternatively, a cleaner solution in my opinion would be to reimplement the `throttled` extender to add the ability to update immediately.

```
ko.extenders['throttleEx'] = function(target, timeout) {
    // Throttling means two things:

    // (1) For dependent observables, we throttle *evaluations* so that, no matter how fast its dependencies
    //     notify updates, the target doesn't re-evaluate (and hence doesn't notify) faster than a certain rate
    target['throttleEvaluation'] = timeout;

    // (2) For writable targets (observables, or writable dependent observables), we throttle *writes*
    //     so the target cannot change value synchronously or faster than a certain rate
    var writeTimeoutInstance = null;
    var throttled = ko.dependentObservable({
        'read': target,
        'write': function(value) {
            clearTimeout(writeTimeoutInstance);
            writeTimeoutInstance = setTimeout(function() {
                target(value);
            }, timeout);
        }
    });

    // add function to set the value directly
    throttled['immediate'] = function(value) {
        target(value);
    };

    return throttled;
};
```

Then to use it:

```
var waiting = ko.computed(function() {
    return outstandingRequests() > 0;
}.extend({ throttleEx: 500 });

// These are called when AJAX requests begin or end
function ajaxBegin() {
    outstandingRequests.immediate(++outstandingRequests());
}
function ajaxEnd() {
    outstandingRequests.immediate(--outstandingRequests());
}
```

Comment: Ah, so `throttle` is just a wrapper, I see. But how can I bind my UI to multiple observables to get the desired behavior?

Comment: For the cleanest implementation, I would probably write my own implementation of the `throttle` extender to add that functionality and use that on your computed observable. Alternatively in your particular case, you could throttle the `outstandingRequests` observable instead of `waiting` and use the approach in my example.

Comment: After having thought about your case, I don't think this is the ideal solution. Although delayed, _any_ change to `outstandingRequests` will trigger an update to `waiting` _eventually_ so quick changes will not lump them all into a single change.  I'll have to rethink that one.

Comment: It's not so much that I want them all lumped together into one change, but rather that I only want the observable to the throttled *sometimes*. In other words, I need a `throttleUnlessNewValueIsZero` extender...

Comment: On second thought, I was wrong about that. After looking back at the implementation of `throttled`, quick changes to the value will still send out only one update. It will still behave pretty much the same.